# error invalid number ORA-01722 in Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I have a  procedure like below, but when I tried to running it using sqlplus its gave me error

> > BEGIN IB_ARCHIVE_FDS('FDS_LOG', 'TIME_REQUEST', 5, 6); END;
> >
> > ERROR at line 1:  ORA-01722: invalid number  ORA-06512: at "NIAGA.IB_ARCHIVE_FDS", line 10 ORA-06512: at line 1

and I'm using Oracle 9i

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Ib_archive_fds(table_name     VARCHAR2,
                                           column_name    VARCHAR2,
                                           success_period NUMBER,
                                           active_period  NUMBER)
IS
  TYPE fds_tabs
    IS TABLE OF ib_fds_log%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  TYPE fds_message_id
    IS TABLE OF ib_fds_log.message_id%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  v_fds_log    FDS_TABS;
  v_message_id FDS_MESSAGE_ID;
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    bulk   collect INTO v_fds_log
    FROM   ib_fds_log2
    WHERE  direction = 0
           AND status_fds_message = 0
           AND time_request < Trunc(SYSDATE - ' || SUCCESS_PERIOD || ' - 1);

    FOR i IN 1 .. v_fds_log.last LOOP
        V_message_id(i) := V_fds_log(i).message_id;
    END LOOP;

    forall indx IN 1 .. v_fds_log.count
      INSERT INTO ib_fds_log3
      VALUES V_fds_log(indx);

    COMMIT;

    forall indx IN 1 .. v_fds_log.count
      DELETE FROM ib_fds_log2
      WHERE  message_id = V_message_id(indx);

    COMMIT;
END;
```

can somebody help me to solve my problem here.

Comment: What does `sysdate - ' || SUCCESS_PERIOD || '- 1` do?

Comment: @Colin'tHart - it throws an ORA-01722, mostly...

Comment: That's what I thought, but being Monday morning I wasn't so sure.

Comment: SUCCESS_PERIOD is number type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I agree with David's analysis of the shortcomings of your implementation the actual cause of that error message is this bug:

```
time_request < trunc(sysdate - ' || SUCCESS_PERIOD || '- 1);
```

`SUCCESS_PERIOD` is a parameter and you presumably want to use it in your date calculation.  However you have coded it as a string; a string is not a number and so we cannot use in in a substraction.

I'm not quite sure what arithmetic you're trying to achieve, but I think you want either this ...

```
time_request < trunc(sysdate - ( SUCCESS_PERIOD - 1));
```

... or this ...

```
time_request < trunc(sysdate - ( SUCCESS_PERIOD + 1) );
```

... depending on how you want to modify the value of `SUCCESS_PERIOD`.

Comment: hi @APC, thans for replying me.

Comment: i tried to change my code like what u suggest here. but it gave me new error.. ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Comment: What is the data type of TIME_REQUEST?  You cannot expect us to debug your code unless you provide all the necessary information.

Comment: @DevYudh - you haven't said which line the new error is on, but I'm pretty sure you're now hitting the mistake @DanielHilgarth pointed out earlier. `v_fds_log.last` is a reference to a record, not a number. But hopefully you are following David's advice and avoiding the cursors completely, so this is academic...

Comment: @APC success_period was NUMBER data type.

Comment: @Alex Poole on line 10, at SUCCESS_PERIOD,

Answer (score 4):

This code should almost certainly avoid the cursors completely and just use SQL statements -- something along the lines of ...

```
procedure ib_archive_fds(
  table_name     varchar2,
  column_name    varchar2,
  success_period number  ,
  active_period  number  )
is
  time_request_limit date;
begin
  time_request_limit := trunc(sysdate - success_period - 1)

  insert into
    ib_fds_log3
  select
    *
  from
    ib_fds_log2
  where
    direction          = 0 and
    status_fds_message = 0 and
    time_request       < ib_archive_fds.time_request_limit;

  delete from
    ib_fds_log2
  where
    direction          = 0 and
    status_fds_message = 0 and
    time_request       < ib_archive_fds.time_request_limit;
end;
```

Various enhancements would be possible if the result set of the query is not constant when this is executed, but all of the PL/SQL is just asking for errors and performance problems.

Comment: I'm really at a loss to understand what `sysdate - ' || success_period || '- 1` does.

Comment: Indeed. Looks like date arithmetic. Corrected my version.

Comment: yes you're right @david,